# OUTPUT Clause in Sql Server (Transact-SQL)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I Know that `OUTPUT Clause` can be used in `INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, or MERGE statement`. The results of an `OUTPUT` clause in a `INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, or MERGE statements` can be stored into a `target table`.

But, when i run this query

```
select   * from  <Tablename>  output
```

I didn't get any error. The query executed as like  select * from  tablename with out any error and with same no. of rows

So what is the exact use of output clause in select statement. If any then how it can be used?
I searched for the answer but i couldn't find a answer!!

Comment: That is an alias in the example in your question.

Comment: @MartinSmith - can we keep keywords as alias with out square brackets

Comment: Some keywords, yes. This is not actually a [*reserved* keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822.aspx)

Comment: @MartinSmith Oh I dont know that. Thank you

Comment: @MartinSmith - Can you post your comment as answer so that i can mark it as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query in your question is in the same category of errors as the following (that I have also seen on this site)

```
SELECT *
FROM   T1 NOLOCK 

SELECT *
FROM   T1
       LOOP JOIN T2
         ON X = Y
```

The first one just ends up aliasing T1 AS NOLOCK. The correct syntax for the hint would be `(NOLOCK)` or ideally `WITH(NOLOCK)`.

The second one aliases T1 AS LOOP. To request a nested loops join the syntax would need to be `INNER LOOP JOIN`

Similarly in your question it just ends up applying the table alias of `OUTPUT` to your table.

None of OUTPUT, LOOP, NOLOCK are actually [reversed keywords](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822.aspx) in TSQL so it is valid to use them as a table alias without needing to quote them, e.g. in square brackets.

Answer (score 1):

[OUTPUT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564(v=sql.110).aspx) clause  return information about the rows affected by a statement. `OUTPUT` Clause is used along with `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE`, or `MERGE` statements as you mentioned. The reason it is used is because these statements themselves  just return the number of rows effected not the rows effected. Thus the usage of `OUTPUT` with `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE`, or `MERGE` statements helps the user by returning actual rows effected.

`SELECT` statement itself returns the rows and `SELECT` doesn't effect any rows. Thus the usage of `OUTPUT` clause  with `SELECT` is not required or supported. If you want to store the results of a `SELECT` statement into a target table use [SELECT INTO](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190750(v=sql.105).aspx) or the standard [INSERT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd776381(v=sql.105).aspx) along with the `SELECT` statement.

**EDIT**

I guess I misunderstood your question. AS @Martin Smith mentioned its is acting an alias in the SELECT statement you mentioned.

Comment: I didn't get you exactly. Are you trying to say that output clause is not supported with Select statemnt.

Comment: How can we keep keywords as alias name without square brackets. Is that possible

Comment: Yes as long as its not a reserved word.

Answer (score 1):

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdelete') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE tempdelete
GO

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#asd') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #asd
GO


CREATE TABLE tempdelete (
    name NVARCHAR(100)
)

INSERT INTO tempdelete VALUES ('a'),('b'),('c')

--Creating empty temp table with the same columns as tempdelete
SELECT * INTO #asd FROM tempdelete WHERE 1 = 0

DELETE FROM tempdelete 
OUTPUT deleted.* INTO #asd

SELECT * FROM #asd
```

This is how you can put all the deleted records in to a table. The problem with that is that you have to define the table with all the columns matching the table from which you are deleting. This is how i do it.

Comment: I didn't ask this!! check @MartinSmith reply to the question. He already answered!!